# Authorization not working in Chrome browser

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, authentication

I have set the authorization for the unknown user that if the user is not logged in he should not be able to view the inner pages of the website. I have done the following things as per the standard rule.

I have set the authorization for my application in such a way that the inner pages of the website cannot be viewed unless and otherwise he/she logs in. I have done the following things as per the standard rule.

```
<location path="User">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
 </location>
  <system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

The things are working properly for me in Firefox and Internet Explorer, but not in the Google chrome. I tried with some of the settings, still it was not working. Please help

Comment: Assuming you've got a directory called `MembersOnly` is this config file in there?

Comment: @Izzy: I dont have a directory as such. Is there any relation with these to browsers ?

Comment: I remember I had a similar issue to what you've got a while back. I added all the internal pages to a different directory and then added a separate config file in that particular directory and it seemed to work for me :/

Comment: hehehhe, that's nice to hear, but I dont have any directory and `MembersOnly`in config file. Do you want to view my config file code ?

Comment: Not really, because the code you've pasted is more than enough. You can however paste you directory structure

Comment: which directory structure. ?